# How to fix the recursive codeso that it has the same asymptotic running time as the iterative version (but is still recursive)

Tags: data-structures, runtime, computer-science, complexity-theory

I was struggling to figure out what changes need to be made to the recursive version of my code below so that the asymptotic run time just about matches the iterative version. Of course, the recursive version of the code still needs to be recursive, but I was stuck on how I should approach cutting down the run time on the recursion.

```
def binarySearch(alist, item): //ITERATIVE VERSION
    first = 0
    last = len(alist)-1
    found = False
    while first<=last and not found:
        midpoint = (first + last)/2
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            if item < alist[midpoint]:
                last = midpoint-1
            else:
                first = midpoint+1
    return found

def binarySearch(alist, item): //RECURSIVE VERSION
    if len(alist) == 0:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = len(alist)/2
        if alist[midpoint]==item:
            return True
        else:
            if item<alist[midpoint]:
                return binarySearch(alist[:midpoint],item)
            else:
                return binarySearch(alist[midpoint+1:],item)
```

Tried to replicate my function recursively, but the asymptotic running time was much slower than the iterative version.

Comment: Don't copy the arrays as you recur. Change your signature to `def binarySearch(alist, item, start, end):` and update the `start` and `end` rather than copying the array with `[:midpoint]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive version creates new lists -- which is detrimental to both time and space complexity.

So instead of slicing `alist`, use `first` and `last` like you did in the iterative version:

```
def binarySearch(alist, item, first=0, last=None):
    if last is None:
        last = len(alist) - 1
    if last < first:
        return False
    else:
        midpoint = (start + end) // 2
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            return True
        elif item < alist[midpoint]:
            return binarySearch(alist, item, first, midpoint - 1)
        else:
            return binarySearch(alist, item, midpoint + 1, last)
```